# What are some properties of free modules over a ring? What makes the notion interesting?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have seen the definition of a free module M over a ring R, but after googling a bit I couldn't find any resources that explained what motivates the notion or what are some interesting properties free R-modules have. I'd be interested in anything that makes them interesting?

Comment: In many ways the set (category) of free modules over a given ring has same properties as vector spaces, which after all are free modules over a field.

Comment: Maps $R^n\to R^m$, $n,m$ finite can be described matricially, which makes it easier to use techniques from linear algebra over fields for the general context of a ring, and linear algebra over fields is much easier. Also they are projective and projective modules are nice. Also they can be described as direct sums of the (second) simplest $R$-module : $R$; thus we have a really good chance of understanding them

Comment: A free module has a basis, and so basically everything you can do with a vector space basis applies.